# Trigger entry event when new rows are added to data extension [Salesforce Marketing Cloud]

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

We're using a Facebook lead capture form, which loads new entries through to a data extension in real time. We've then set up a Journey Builder journey to send an email to records that enter the data extension. But I'm having trouble finding a way to configure the Entry Event so that it runs in real time, detecting whenever a new row has been added to the data extension. Best I can manage at the moment is to have it running on a schedule every hour.

Is there a way to configure an Entry Event so that it detects when a new row has been added to a Data Extension and fires automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Its simple if you have created your facebook lead capture form and selected a cloud page data extension to capture the records then you can create an entry event "cloud page form submit event" and use this entry event in your journey. this way as soon as a subscriber comes in to your cloud page DE journey will trigger an email.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks heaps for responding. I'm not sure how to create a cloud pages data extension, but we haven't used cloud pages before. I'll look into it. Do you know of any guides or documentation of the process?

Comment: Creating a smart capture data extension can be done by creating a new data extension, based on a template. Can you confirm though, that if we do that and add  row to it - it can fire immediately?